# Problem accessing the remote working space on my new SBS 2008 box

Tags: remote-access, windows-sbs-2008

This supposedly easy to install OS is starting to drive me nuts...
SYMPTOMS:
When trying to connect to the remote workplace I get (and ignore) the security warning because I am currently testing with the self issued certificate. After loggin in the remote workplace's main screen displays but the images on it do not load. When I try to click the email link I am thrown back to the login screen. If I try the login to exchange directly by typing in the remote.mydomain.com/owa  address I get a 403 error that I am denied access. The problem occurs on both a vista and a win 7 machine. It seems that some security setting is playing tricks with me. How can I troubleshoot this?

Answer (score 0):

I have to investigate further, but it seems to be a problem at the laptops, not at the server. I will post what was wrong if I think it will be of general interest.

Comment: very strange. did you get any closer to working out what's going on?